# MathJax in comment looks like nonsense, what's going on?

Tags: bug, mathjax, comment

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4822513), I have added a comment:

$(a-p)^2+(4-a-q)^2 = a^2-2ap+p^2+(4-a)^2-2(4-a)q+q^2= a^2-2ap+(4-a)^2-2(4-a)q+1= ...$, does this help?

But is looks like this:

[image]

For your information: I'm surfing with Google Chrome in incognito mode, on a Windows $10$ computer.

**Edit after [Asaf](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/622/asaf-karagila)'s comment:**
As it seems to work on another computer, I thought the issue might be caused by the fact that my window is maximised, so I used a normal window and then it's also bad, but in another sense:

[image]

(You clearly see the formula passing out of the intended "column".)

Comment: Looks absolutely fine on my Android phone with Firefox.

Comment: MathJax has been broken like this ever since SE switched to the responsive design.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist: I never heard of responsive design, but apparently there even is such a tag on StackExchange's meta. You might leave this question here or migrate it to StackExchange's meta (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design), I don't know what is best suited for getting this fixed (if there ever are plans for getting such issues fixed).

Comment: This has been reported in a bunch of places at Meta SE itself (for example, [MathJax not rendering properly in comment on mobile-sized screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379980)). I don't have any hope that this will get fixed anytime soon.

Comment: I used to face this problem in past, but as of now it looks fine on my Android phone with Firefox browser.

Comment: FYI, you can use display mode (double \$\$) inside comments. Maybe that's a better option when sticking a big chunk of LaTeX in the comments?

Comment: You might be interested in using the `{align}` environment or one of its variants in MathJax to explicitly tell how a run-on equation should be split across lines.  See [this section](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5024#5024) of the MathJax Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394078), the MathJax wrapping bug has finally be marked as "status-review."  The post incorrectly states that the recent color changes brought back the bug.  The bug is over 2 years old.